# What is the difference between explicitly specifying a return statement in JS vs not having a return statement at all?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am maintaining some old code and I noticed that there are many instances where the old programmer left  `return;` statements as the final line in most of his functions. Is there any advantage to this? I feel like this is a waste of space, so I have been removing them as I see them. Is one of them generally faster?

Comment: It's very important if it occurs in the middle of a function (like, inside a loop, or `if` clause, or whatever), but not if it's at the very end of the function. There'll be no measurable performance difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1):

> When the [[Call]] internal method for a Function object *F* is called
>   with a this value and a list of arguments, the following steps are
>   taken:
>
> 1. Let *funcCtx* be the result of establishing a new execution context for function code using the value of *F*'s [[FormalParameters]] internal
>      property, the passed arguments [List](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.8) *args*, and the **this** value as
>      described in [10.4.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3).
> 2. Let result be the result of evaluating the *FunctionBody* that is the value of *F*'s [[Code]] internal property. If F does not have a [[Code]]
>      internal property or if its value is an empty *FunctionBody*, then
>      *result* is (normal, undefined, empty).
> 3. Exit the execution context *funcCtx*, restoring the previous execution context.
> 4. If *result*.type is throw then throw *result*.value.
> 5. If *result*.type is return then return *result*.value.
> 6. Otherwise *result*.type must be normal. Return **undefined**.

In other words, if the function that is called has no explicit `return` statement, then it implicitly returns `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks, this answered it perfectly, +1 for ECMAScript Language Specification.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement is used to return a value from the function. You do not have to use a return statement; the program will return when it reaches the end of the function. If no return statement is executed in the function, or if the return statement has no expression, the function returns the value **undefined**.

```
return; //undefined


return
a+b; 
// is transformed by ASI into
return;
a+b;
```

So you get undefined again.

Take a look at MDN documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

By the way, I found this link about performance and I've found a test that compares 4 expression, two function with a return and the same function without return.

[Here](http://jsperf.com/returnfunctions) you can see the test. Hope it is related with your question

Comment: Sure, but doesn't really address the question, AFAICT.